# How can I call resolve in a promise while looping through an object that only meets certain conditions?

Tags: arrays, object, promise, settimeout

I have a function that contains a promise that contains a setTimeout function. The set timeout function loops through an axios call that spreads out calls to avoid a rate limit error. This works great, albeit a bit slow. What I would like to do is redirect after all calls have been completed. I set the remainder to equal the last element returned. Where I am confused on how to compare that to the array of arrays in the foreach loop. Would the best approach here be to create a new array of the indexes returned that meet the if condition? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated?

I've tried to create a new array based on value and index but I'm a bit rusty on how to do that properly inside the if condition

```
async function axiosRequest() {
   let newT = {
       value: {
           test: 't',
           test2: 't2',
           test3: 't3',
           test4: 't4',
           test5: '',
           test6: ''
       }
   }
   let contianerT = [];
   const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

       for (let m in contianerT) {
           let remainder = Object.keys(contianerT[m].value).length

           Object.entries(contianerT[m].value).forEach(([key, value], index, array) => {
               let newArray = [];
               if (value !== "") { //don't loop through empty values 
                   //  let len = Object.keys(value).length
                   //let last_element = sortedKeys[sortedKeys.length - 1];
                   setTimeout(() => {
                       remainder--;
                      //axios.post('/url',{key: key, value: value}) lives here 
                       //  len --;
                       console.log(remainder)
                       //console.log(len)
                       //console.log(index)
                       if (remainder === index) {
                           resolve();
                       }

                   }, 500 * index);
               }
           });
       }
   });
   await promise
}
axiosRequest()
   .then(() => {
       console.log('redirect')
   })
```

The result should loop through the length of the Objects and return the resolve function if the last elements match(if they have reached the end)

Comment: It would help if your code was properly indented.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry about that I've cleaned it up

Comment: Where the actual asynchronous operation in this code?  I don't see one.

Comment: There are much, much better ways to keep from hitting rate limiting that just prescheduling the whole loop of events with delayed timers.  Plus it wrecks your control when you have all these things scheduled with timers.  We can help you better if you show us the real asynchronous operation you're trying to accomplish and you explain the actual rate limiting restrictions you have to follow.

Comment: @jfriend00 I took it out for simplicity - it just takes in the key and value returned in the loop.  I'm just looking see how I can get to the resolve method. Normally remainder === 0 would make sense here but because empty values are not applied  the remainder will not always be 0. I'm thinking to resolve this It might make more sense to create the object independent of empty values then proceed to loop through it?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks I'm calling the request inside the setTimeout. The actual code is set up in service so it wouldn't make sense here it just looks like your standard post request. I've tried using axios-rate-limit on the post request but found it did not work with the redirect so I found this method. The rate limit is 40 request per 1000 ms

Comment: Still trying to understand what you're trying to accomplish?  What does this "how to compare that to the array of arrays in the foreach loop" mean?  In one part of the question, it appears you're just trying to avoid rate limiting and know when all requests are done.  In another part of the question you ask about comparing an array of arrays which I have no idea what that is.  Sorry, but I can't really tell what you need help with?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I was trying to set the scope of the problem. The underlying issue is I'm uncertain on how to reach the resolve method to get to the redirect after the last element in the loop has been reached in the axiosRequest method (after the seTimout  has reached the last index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like you're just trying to figure out how to know when the last request is done.  For that, I'd suggest just pushing all the promises into an array  and use `Promise.all()` on the array of promises to know when they are all done.  That way `Promise.all()` does all the work for you of maintaining counters to know when all the requests are done.

I've also replaced your use of `setTimeout()` with a promise-based utility function `delay()` that mixes better with promises.

```
// helper function that returns a promise 
// that resolves after a timeout time
function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(v);
        }, t);
    });
}

function axiosRequest() {
   let newT = {
       value: {
           test: 't',
           test2: 't2',
           test3: 't3',
           test4: 't4',
           test5: '',
           test6: ''
       }
   }
   let promises = [];
   let contianerT = [];
   for (let m of contianerT) {
       Object.entries(contianerT[m].value).forEach(([key, value], index, array) => {
           if (value !== "") { //don't loop through empty values 
               //  let len = Object.keys(value).length
               //let last_element = sortedKeys[sortedKeys.length - 1];
               promises.push(delay(500 * index).then(() =>
                   return axios.post('/url',{key: key, value: value});    // I assume this returns a promise
               }));
           }
       });
   }
   // returns a promise that resolves to an array of axios.post() results
   return Promise.all(promises);
}

axiosRequest().then(() => {
   console.log('redirect');
});
```

Notes:

1. I've assumed that `axios.post()` returns a promise that resolves to it's returned value.
2. I did not attempt to rewrite/fix your delay to get around rate limiting.  What you have is very primitive and will likely not be sufficient if `contianerT` is a large array.
3. Arrays should be iterated with `for/of`, not `for/in` because `for/in` iterates object properties, not array elements.  So, `for (let m in contianerT)` does not look correct.  Also, note that most people spell it "container".

P.S. Normally, I don't even engage in questions that are predominantly pseudo-code because often the questioner doesn't even know all the problems to ask about or isn't asking the right question and we can be so much more accurate in offering the best answer when we can see the real code.  Please post your REAL code next time.  You will be pleasantly surprised how much better people can help you and how much more help you will get for things you didn't even know there was a better way to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for the feedback and catching the typo. I can't provide all the files at this time, however, what I do have is compiling so I wouldn't call it pseudo-code but I will be more concise next time. I'm unable to compile the snippet you provided but I understand the logic using the delay then returning Promise.all so I'll work on getting that to work.

Comment: @BluLotus - What error do you get?  Perhaps a typo in my answer, but you should be able to get the general idea, right?

Comment: @BluLotus - I fixed a typo.